# kubernetes: Error deploying dashboard (ui)

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I have successfully set up a kubernetes cluster on AWS using `kops` and the following commands:

```
$ kops create cluster --name=<my_cluster_name> --state=s3://<my-state-bucket> --zones=eu-west-1a --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.small --dns-zone=<my-cluster-dns>

$ kops update cluster <my-cluster-name> --yes
```

The cluster has 1 master and 2 slaves.

I am trying to deploy the dashboard using the following command, as per [these guidelines](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard):

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

**1**.

I get the following error:

```
secret "kubernetes-dashboard-certs" created
serviceaccount "kubernetes-dashboard" created
error: error validating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": error validating data: unknown object type schema.GroupVersionKind{Group:"rbac.authorization.k8s.io", Version:"v1", Kind:"Role"}; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

**2**.

My dashboard is not accessible via `https://<my_master_node_public_ip>/ui`

Instead, I get the following:

```
kind    "Status"
apiVersion  "v1"
metadata    {}
status  "Failure"
message "endpoints \"kubernetes-dashboard\" not found"
reason  "NotFound"
details 
name    "kubernetes-dashboard"
kind    "endpoints"
code    404
```

**3**.

After running

```
kubectl proxy
```

and trying to access the dashboard via:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

as instructed by the relevant guidelines, I have the exact same problem.

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.1", GitCommit:"f38e43b221d08850172a9a4ea785a86a3ffa3b3a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-11T23:27:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.11", GitCommit:"b13f2fd682d56eab7a6a2b5a1cab1a3d2c8bdd55", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-11-25T17:51:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**edit**: here is the outcome when turning validation errors off:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml --validate=false
secret "kubernetes-dashboard-certs" configured
serviceaccount "kubernetes-dashboard" configured
service "kubernetes-dashboard" created
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": Role in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Role: no kind "Role" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": RoleBinding in version "v1" cannot be handled as a RoleBinding: no kind "RoleBinding" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": Deployment in version "v1beta2" cannot be handled as a Deployment: no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1beta2"
```

Comment: It always is useful for others who want to help you to include the Kubernetes version you're dealing with, that is, include the output of `kubectl version` in your question. That said, my hunch is it's RBAC-related,  so I'd suggest to try one of the recipes in http://docs.heptio.com/content/tutorials/rbac.html to give the `kube-system:default` service account the necessary rights.

Comment: updated with `k8s` version

Comment: Thank you for adding the version. Now, I missed the original error, so what does `kubectl get po -n kube-system | grep kubernetes-dashboard` give you?

Comment: nothing...empty result!

Comment: question also updated with sequence of `kops` commands used to set up the cluster

Comment: OK, that explains it. What you should see is a pod running there. So what likely happened when you did `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml` it failed to create the role and stopped there. Since you're using a Kube dash manifest that is for 1.8 and you're using 1.7 in kops that's no surprise.

Comment: So the prosposed solution is to update `kops` to `1.8` ? (apologies I am a newbie and I do not know what a `Kube dash manifest` is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're provisioning a Kubernetes 1.7 cluster with kops and using a [dashboard manifest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml) file for Kubernetes 1.8 so try the following (nuke the current deployment first), then:

```
$ kops create cluster --kubernetes-version="1.8.1" --name=<my_cluster_name> --state=s3://<my-state-bucket> --zones=eu-west-1a --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.small --dns-zone=<my-cluster-dns>
```

As pointed out by [pkaramol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2409793/pkaramol), alternatively to above you can upgrade kops to 1.8 and it should also work.

Note that in any case, in order to get to the dashboard, do:

```
$ kubectl proxy
```

... and then the dashboard should be accessible via http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Comment: I accepted your answer thx. However I resolved it by upgrading to `kops` to 1.8. It is accessible via the `localhost` url, however the `https://<public_ip_of_master>/ui` is still not working, giving `Error: 'malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"'
Trying to reach: 'http://100.96.2.4:8443/'`

Comment: Thanks! Ah OK, yeah upgrading kops is also possible, as long as you create a 1.8 cluster. IIRC the `https://<public_ip_of_master>/ui` URL is deprecated so need to use `kubectl proxy` and then access via http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ … can you confirm that works?

Comment: OK, will add that as well …